# Multiple Instances of an app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I need to deploy several instances of the same app on heroku. It appears that I need to have a branch and local repo for each instance to deploy each instance to heroku via the cli. This just doesnt seem right.

Does anyone have any experience in this area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to have a git remote set up for each heroku app, but you can push to any remote from one local repo.

You can use the `heroku git:remote` command to set up multiple git remotes for your multiple heroku apps. Run that command with `--help` to see all the options, but this would create a git remote called `staging` for a heroku app named `chunky-bacon-1234`:

```
$ heroku git:remote -r staging -a chunky-bacon-1234
```

Then, if you wanted to deploy your local branch named `my-experiment` to that heroku app, you can push that branch to the remote's master branch:

```
$ git push staging my-experiment:master
```

Comment: Thanks carolclarinet, so i could do something like: 
`heroku git:remote -r cust1_production -a chunky-bacon-1234`
`heroku git:remote -r cust2_production -a chunky-bacon-1234`
etc for each customer instance?

Comment: Yup, where `chunky-bacon-1234` isn't repeated-- that would be the name of each heroku instance.